# How to stop contact registration from Android App to Salesforce marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, mobileconnect, android, mobilepush-android

How do I stop auto contact registration from Android app into marketing cloud. I've already integrated android app with sales cloud and also storing device id etc. in sales cloud. Same is subsequently synced with marketing cloud through sales cloud. Now I don't want to register contacts directly into marketing cloud from android app as I'm already getting this from sales cloud.

What changes need to be done in [standard integration code](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/sdk-implementation/implement-sdk-google.html) so that I would be able to send push notification but do not register any contact directly from into marketing cloud.

Note - We don't want to push custom contact key through app into marketing cloud due to some complexities and hence need some alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, with the SDK, to register your device for push without also registering a device/contact.

In an upcoming release you may delay device registration until a `Contact Key` is set, but as you've noted; you do not want to populate a Contact Key from the application.